# Should I add ParcelJS `.parcel-cache` to CI bitbucket pipeline caches? Is there a benefit?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, parceljs

BitBucket Pipelines have the ability to add custom caches which are reused between pipeline runs. ParcelJS makes use of its own `.parcel-cache` file cache to speed up builds between runs.

I have a team running several CI branches at the same time and we're looking to move to ParcelJS.

As far as I can tell BitBucket creates the same cache regardless of the branch you're on - so I was wondering if it is possible and whether it makes sense to create a custom cache pointing to the `.parcel-cache`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `.parcel-cache` is only good for the development server

> If you restart the dev server, Parcel will only rebuild files that have changed since the last time it ran.

https://parceljs.org/features/development/#caching

I reckon you are running build, lint and test steps in Bitbucket Pipelines so, unless I misunderstand parceljs' cache purpose, you should better **not** save it. Otherwise you would be wasting build time by uploading and downloading a bundle that would not speed-up your scripts in return.

You should test this in your workstation nonetheless. Like, with a clean clone of your repo, does the presence of this cache speed up the instructions that run in the pipeline? If it does, then you can face the issues of cache usefulness across different branches.